# foreach - dopar do not start workers

Tags: r, foreach, domc

I have the following piece of code that I would like to run with the doMC engine:

```
who_wins<-function(probs_a,probs_b,delta_order=0,delta_down=0){
  #browser()
  team_a<-runif(5,0,1)
  team_b<-runif(5,0,1)
  sya<-syb<-0
  for(i in 1:5){
    for(j in 1:2){
      if(j==1){
        if(sya<syb){
          team_a[i]<-(1-delta_down)*team_a[i]
        } 
        team_a[i]<-(1-(i-1)*delta_order)*team_a[i]
        sya<-sya+(team_a[i]<probs_a[i])
      }
      else{
        if(syb<sya){
          team_b[i]<-(1-delta_down)*team_b[i]
        } 
        team_b[i]<-(1-(i-1)*delta_order)*team_b[i]
        syb<-syb+(team_b[i]<probs_b[i])
      }
    }
  }
  if(sya>syb){
    return(1)
  }
  else if(sya<syb){
    return(2)
  }
  else {
    return(0)
  }
}

library(doMC)
registerDoMC(8)

probs_a<-seq(.6,.8,length.out=5)
probs_b<-probs_a[5:1]
nsim<-20000

results<-foreach(icount(nsim), .combine=c) %dopar% {
    return(who_wins(probs_a,probs_b))
}
```

The problem is that a couple of seconds after the first worker starts, the engine tries to launch the remaining. I see an spike in all processors, but they all die quickly, even the first one. Then, a new process is launched and the remaining of the code is run through this lone worker.

I have tried with different pieces of code and the engine works perfectly. But with this specific rutine, it doesn't.

Can anybody tell me what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you include code for the `who_wins` function, particularly if it is simple. Then others can simply grab your code to start experimenting and investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `Sys.sleep(0.01)` inside your loop, I see all 8 processes “busy” with that one. After they are done, the main process remains busy for some time. I assume that the overhead of collecting the data from the individual processes and combining it into a single result is on a similar scale than the actual benefit from the parallelized computation. If you simply change the “computation” to `return(1)`, you will see that this takes about as long as your computation, so the time is not spent on the workload but assembling the result.

Neither `.inorder=FALSE` nor use of `doParallel` instead of `doMC` change this. However, I would consider this a problem in the `foreach` package, as `mclapply` has significantly less overhead:

```
result <- unlist(mclapply(1:nsim, function(i) {
   return(who_wins(probs_a, probs_b))
}, mc.cores=8))
```

Comment: Thanks MvG. Flawless idea! I didn't know about the overhead problems of the foreach loop.

Comment: Neither did I. I was just about to become a major `foreach` fan. Do you want to report this problem to the `foreach` maintainers? Perhaps there is something they can do about it.

Comment: Me too. I was using for almost everything. I have only the email for the docs, do you have any other?

Comment: The [package page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) at CRAN has the maintainer address.

Comment: Done. I pointed them to this discussion. Lets hope they answer my email. Again, thanks.

Comment: @jcredberry How did that turn out?

Comment: It just didn't. I used @MvG's answer and moved on.